# Lift Charts in Multiple Linear Regression

Tags: multiple-regression, data-visualization, data-mining

When lift charts are generated in a Multiple Linear Regression model, for example, in predicting a continuous variable such as price of a car, how can they be explained in evaluating the performance of the model. Lot of examples on the web are related to logistic regression but it is not clear as to why and how lift charts can be used for linear regression models.

Comment: Welcome to CV. You've assumed that everyone knows what a "lift chart" is. That is incorrect. It would be helpful to your future chances of a response if you were to both, provide an explanation as well as an example plot of what you're querying.